# Text moves to side of the page on scroll down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The text moves to the side of the page when using span inside of multiple container.

Edit: This should no longer be a problem in the newest version of bootstrap.

Comment: -1 It would be better to include the substance of the question with relevant code in the body of the question and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Bootstrap documentation website they are using `.span3 { min-height: 1px; }` to prevent column from collapsing.

> **Edit:** This no longer relevant since Bootstrap 2.1.1. They
>   have it fixed by default: `[class*="span"] { min-height: 1px; }`

Answer (score 1):

Put span.span3 {float:left} and span.span9 {float:right}
Make sure that other properties dosen't over-rights those.

Answer (score 0):

I'll freely admit I don't know much about reactive design or the Twitter bootstrap thingy, but your problem is the affix class.

When you scroll down, the class of the menu ul changes from "affix-top" to "affix", which has a position of fixed, which means the menu doesn't have a width so the main content floats over the top of it.

I'm assuming the fixed position is so the menu maintains a constant position in the window.

One quick fix is to give the "affix-top" class a position of fixed as well, then give the main-content a margin so it sits to the right of the menu.